# Struct em C não imprima nada

Tags: c, string, struct

Olá, estou fazendo um programa para faculdade e tenho que adicionar livros em uma struct e depois imprimir seus dados, eu criei um menu de opções e usei ifs como um switch, um dos ifs é usado para adicionar livros a struct e outro para imprimir os nomes dos livros, porém quando executo o if para imprimir os nomes programa não imprime nada e as vezes sai até caracteres estranhos, já usei vários métodos de limpeza como fflush(stdin), setbuf, fgets porém nada deu certo, quando eu tento imprimir dentro do primeiro if ele imprime corretamente mas no outro não, o problema só acorre com strings o reste ele imprime normalmente, segue o codigo. obrigado pela atenção.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

struct livro{
    char titulo[30];
    char autor[30];
    char genero[30];
    int codigo;
    double preco;
};

void mostraTitulos(struct livro x){
    printf("%s\n", x.titulo);
}

main(){
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "portuguese");
    bool loop = true;
    struct livro colecao[50];
    char menu;
    int numLivros = 0;
    int i;
    while(loop){
        printf("Digite I para incluir um livro. \n");
        printf("Digite L para listar o nome de todos os livros. \n");
        printf("Digite A para procurar um livro por autor. \n");
        printf("Digite T para procurar um livro por título. \n");
        printf("Digite M para calcular a média de preço de todos os livros. \n");
        printf("Digite S para sair \n");
        scanf("%s", &menu);
        printf("\n");
        if(menu == 's' || menu == 'S'){
            loop = false;
        }
        if(menu == 'i' || menu == 'I'){
            printf("Digite o título do livro: ");
            scanf("%s", &colecao[numLivros].titulo);

            printf("Digite o autor do livro: ");
            scanf("%s", &colecao[numLivros].autor);

            printf("Digite o gênero do livro: ");
            scanf("%s", &colecao[numLivros].genero);

            printf("Digite o código do livro: ");
            scanf("%i", &colecao[numLivros].codigo);

            printf("Digite o preço do livro: ");
            scanf("%lf", &colecao[numLivros].preco);

            printf("Livro adicionado.\n");
            numLivros++;

        }

        if(menu == 'l' || menu == 'L'){
            for(i = 0; i < numLivros; i++){
                mostraTitulos(colecao[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Não utilize o `&` na função `scanf` quando for ler uma string. Como a variável nenu é um char, e não um array de char,  utilize: ` scanf("%c ", &menu);`.

Answer (score 0):

Olá , Gabriel . Para resolver este problema basta você declarar sua variável "int numLivros = 1;" . Entretanto, eu particularmente faria deste modo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

struct livro{

char titulo[30];
char autor[30];
char genero[30];
int codigo;
double preco;

}colecao[50];



int main(){

setlocale(LC_ALL, "portuguese");
bool loop = true;
char menu;
int numLivros = 0;
int i;

while(loop){

    printf("Digite I para incluir um livro. \n");
    printf("Digite L para listar o nome de todos os livros. \n");
    printf("Digite A para procurar um livro por autor. \n");
    printf("Digite T para procurar um livro por título. \n");
    printf("Digite M para calcular a média de preço de todos os livros. \n");
    printf("Digite S para sair \n");
    scanf("%s", &menu);
    printf("\n");
    if(menu == 's' || menu == 'S'){
        loop = false;
    }
    if(menu == 'i' || menu == 'I'){
        printf("Digite o título do livro: ");
        scanf("%s", &colecao[numLivros].titulo);

        printf("Digite o autor do livro: ");
        scanf("%s", &colecao[numLivros].autor);

        printf("Digite o gênero do livro: ");
        scanf("%s", &colecao[numLivros].genero);

        printf("Digite o código do livro: ");
        scanf("%i", &colecao[numLivros].codigo);

        printf("Digite o preço do livro: ");
        scanf("%lf", &colecao[numLivros].preco);

        printf("Livro adicionado.\n");
        numLivros++;

    }

    if(menu == 'l' || menu == 'L'){
        for(i = 0; i < numLivros; i++){

        printf("%s \n",colecao[i].titulo);

        }
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Olá, quando é adicionado um livro o código incrementa + 1 a variável numLivros, fazendo o ciclo do for funcionar.

Comment: Por qual motivo deveria declarar `int numLivros = 1;` se em C o índice de um array parte de 0?